# Which value is the current maximum at std::max_element with lambda?

Tags: c++, c++17

If I'm using `std::max_element` with a lambda and I have a special value in the row which is always considered to be lower than anything.

So when the parameters are given to the comparison-lambda:
which of both parameters is the current maximum, i.e. the maximum of the values evaluated before?

This would help me in a way that I won't have to check both values for my magic value.

Comment: Could you please add a [mcve] that would make it easier to understand your problem?

Comment: Try reimplementing `max_element` yourself. You should immediately see which parameter is which.

Comment: This question makes the improper assumption that the elements of the collection will be fed into the provided predicate in any particular order. The standard makes no such guarantee.

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element: **Return value**:
Iterator to the greatest element in the range [first, last). If several elements in the range are equivalent to the greatest element, returns the iterator to the first such element. Returns last if the range is empty.

Comment: Your lambda has to do the appropriate comparison so that it with always returns true if the special value is on the left side only and false if it is on the right side (or both side). After that, you make you _regular_ comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The `Compare` functor must implement strict weak ordering - acting as `<`(less than). It is not specified which parameter is the current maximum. It must be one of them because exactly N-1 comparisons are made. But it can be either of them depending on the `if` statement used in the for loop.

The logic then dictates that the larger of those parameters will be the new maximum.

Comment: I've been looking, and it doesn't seem like the standard actually requires the Compare functor to implement strict weak ordering. It *should* if OP wants to induce a "valid" ordering upon their set.

Comment: @AndyG You might be right, cppreference states it must satisfy `Compare` concept, which requires S-W order, but the Standard only requires that the found `max` satisfies `bool(invoke(comp, max, e)) ==false` for all `e` in the range. But I do not believe that can be satisfied in O(N) unless `comp` implements the ordering. [Standard ref](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/alg.min.max)

Comment: @AndyG Actually no, the Standard also assumes `Compare` implements ordering - see [28.7.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/alg.sorting#2).

Comment: Thanks for poking around some more. All it says is "an ordering relation" which permits it to be more relaxed than strict weak ordering

Comment: Better to stay with strict weak ordering to ensure you get consistant result whatever the input data is... It make the code less fragile.

Comment: Why should that because there are N-1 comparisons, @AndyG ???

Comment: @BonitaMontero: Implementers are allowed to do whatever they want so long as they satisfy the standard's requirements (and even then sometimes implementations do their own thing and hopefully document it as an exception). Point is, unless the standard explicitly says that comparisons happen in some order, we cannot make that assumption. You could take a look at the source of the standard library you are using for your platform and see what they are doing, but again unless they document it as an explicit "feature", it cannot be relied upon.